# Testing rxjs: How to fake-click an element and check the resulting stream with marble diagrams?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, rxjs, reactive-programming

My intent: I have a view component that emits a stream of instructions on clicks
to its members. I want to test that clicking on the buttons emits the
instructions in the expected order for all interactive elements.

I've compiled a small example with the buttons `a` and `b`, which should emit
the strings `'a'` and `'b'` into the same observable.

I'll add the import statements for convenience:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing/TestScheduler';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do;
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
```

Create a container, and append both `a` and `b` buttons.

```
const container = document.createElement('div');
const a = document.createElement('button');
const b = document.createElement('button');
container.append(a);
container.append(b);
```

Create click streams from both buttons' click events and merge them.

```
const stream = Observable.merge(
  Observable.fromEvent(a, 'click').map(() => 'a'),
  Observable.fromEvent(b, 'click').map(() => 'b')
);
```

Create a test scheduler for marble-tests.

```
const marbles = new TestScheduler((x, y) => expect(x).to.deep.equal(y));
```

This cold observable *should*, as a side-effect, click on the buttons. I'm not
sure it does, in fact, I'm pretty sure it doesn't. **Why?**

```
marbles.createColdObservable('-a-b', { a, b }).do(element => $(element).click());
```

I expect to see the emissions of both buttons as per definition of `const stream` above.

```
marbles.expectObservable(stream).toBe('-a-b');
marbles.flush();
```

The result is:

```
AssertionError: expected [] to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]
```

Because no click events ever get generated. Why? I'm assuming that my assumption
is wrong that the above code actually generates click events. If so, (how else)
can I test *actual DOM click events* using marble diagrams?

Note: this is a minimal example, the actual code I want to test is more complex,
and involves some buttons changing state as a result of conditions I manipulate
via other marble diagrams. I would not want to test `Observable.fromEvent`, I'd
like to test that my stream definition in `const stream` does the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to subscribe to the cold observable created via marbles.

```
marbles
  .createColdObservable('-a-b', { a, b })
  .do(element => $(element).click())
  .subscribe();
```

Otherwise the marbles' side-effects don't get executed. Stupid mistake on my part, it turned out!

Comment: I have a similar scenario and it didn't succeed. I'm using RxJS v6. `fromEvent` adds an event listener when you subscribe to `stream` observable. So I don't understand how can the clicks get through the logic before subscribing to the observable. Any thoughts?